# How to process Stripe payment authentication in iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I don't know if there's a lot of people people in here who are familiar with Stripe, but I hope someone can help me out. I'm setting up iDEAL payment in my app using Sources, and I'm using the guide on the Stripe website to help me out. Everything was explained very clear about how to set up the source, but the problem I'm running into is that the guide is very unclear about how I should continue after the source has been created and the user has authenticated the payment. It only describes how to continue when you're a web developer, but it's very unclear how to continue when you're an iOS developer. Basically what I want to do, is to get notified on whether the source object became chargeable (successful authentication) or failed. It only says you can get notified about the authentication status through client-side polling, but it's poorly described how to set up client-side polling in iOS. Can someone give me some directions on how I should continue after the authentication has been completed and the user returns back to the app? How can I get access to the new status of the source object after I return to the app?

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful response if you distill your question to exactly the issue you're having and post the code you've used to try to solve the problem.

Comment: @nathan I'm not having an issue with code I've used. I've done everything correctly and I'm merely asking what the next step is in the process (which I think I've done pretty clearly to anyone who's slightly familiar with Stripe).

Comment: I'm not saying your question is unclear. I'm just trying to help you out since I can't answer your question. Most people will not read a wall of text. The type of person who can answer your question will want immediate evidence (code) that you've put in some effort already.

Comment: @nathan Thank you, I appreciate your concern, but I think the people who are familiar with Stripe will know I already put in some effort, since I described the steps I already completed successfully.

Comment: Yes, but they won't actually read that far to know! A lot of people scan the question and if they see a wall of text with no code blocks — skip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to charge a given source or create a customer in your iOS application as those calls require your Secret API key. You should never have the Secret API key in your iOS application otherwise an attacker could get his hands on it and then create charges, refunds or transfers on your behalf.

Once the source is created client-side, you need to send its id `src_XXXX` to your server. There, you will be able to call the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#source-confirmation) to charge your source with your Secret API key.

Since you plan to use iDeal, the source is not chargeable immediately. Instead, you need to either [poll](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#source-confirmation) the source client-side until it's ready to be charged or you need to listen for the `source.chargeable` [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) event indicating that the source is ready to be charged.

Once it is ready, you will be able to [charge the source](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#charge-request) on your server.

Comment: So, in order to poll client-side I need to create a `Stripe.js` file and upload it to my web server? Because if it is, I don't understand why it's called CLIENT side polling. Wouldn't the actual polling happen on the server side if I'm supposed to use a .js file on my server? I don't get what the client has to do with it. That's what I had the most trouble with. I still don't understand where to get the file, where to put it, and what to add to it.

Comment: You can poll client-side if you prefer and this is all covered in details in the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/sources#redirecting-your-customer

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had no idea the `STPAPIClient` had a polling method. Like I said, the guide on the Stripe website is very confusing and incomplete. It only says I can poll with the .js file or with webhooks, and even a member of customer support told me to do this, even though I had clearly explained I'm an iOS developer. The implementaion turned out to be a simple process, but it was made so difficult because of a poor helping guide.

Comment: @MarkCarols Can you please explain me the whole thing clearly, I'm also confused with the  procedure